# Excel COUNTIFS count months in date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm currently using the `=COUNTIFS()` function to count the number of values that satisfy two conditions.

```
=COUNTIFS('2014'!$F:$F, B3, '2014'!$H:$H, A13)
```

However I no want to also include specific months as a condition, but the range of dates is in the format, 3/11/2014. I have looked up a few different ways that can count specific months from a list of dates using a combination of the `=SUMPRODUCT()` and `MONTH` formulas, but unable to find one that works in a `COUNTIFS` function to satisfy the original conditions also.

I even tried to think outside of the box by using wild cards,

```
=COUNTIFS('2014'!$F:$F, B3, '2014'!$H:$H, A13, '2014'!$A:$A, "*/11/2014")
```

Alas to no avail.

Does anyone know if there is a way in which to include counting specific months to a `=COUNTIFS()` function?

EDIT*

I have a temporary fix, thats not a sure fire solution, but I have created a helper column containing

```
=TEXT(A1, "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

And tied this in with my original wild card solution

```
=COUNTIFS('2014'!$F:$F, B3, '2014'!$H:$H, A13, '2014'!$I:$I, "*/11/2014")
```

however still after something a little less bodgy!

Comment: Are all the dates from year 2014?

Comment: Yes they are all from the year 2014 thank you.

Comment: And your data is `d/mm/yyyy` ?

Comment: Yes thats correct, all `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: If you type `=TODAY()` in a cell do you get `02/25/2015` or `25/02/2015`?

Comment: `=TODAY()` returns `25/02/2015`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that *all* your dates for excel are set to the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` this formula should work:

```
=COUNTIFS('2014'!$F:$F, B3, '2014'!$H:$H, A13, '2014'!$A:$A, ">="&EOMONTH(DATE(2014,10,1),0)+1,'2014'!$A:$A,"<"&EOMONTH(DATE(2014,11,1),0)+1)
```

This basically checks the column against the span of the entire month.  All dates **greater or equal to** the start of the desired month, and all dates **less than** the start of the next month.

To change the month:

```
=COUNTIFS('2014'!$F:$F, B3, '2014'!$H:$H, A13, '2014'!$A:$A, ">="&EOMONTH(DATE(2014,10,1),0)+1,'2014'!$A:$A,"<"&EOMONTH(DATE(2014,11,1),0)+1)
                                                                                    ^^ change 10 to one month prior               ^^ change 11 to the month you want.
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach - especially for large ranges - but generically I suggest always using >=1st and < 1st of next month, which would always correctly capture all dates in the month ( and no dates from other months) even if time values are included

Answer (score 1):

For example for January you might incorporate something like:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">"&41639,A:A,"<"&41650)
```

assuming your dates are numeric rather than strings.

Answer (score 0):

If the month you are testing against is numerical format (January is 1, Feb is 2, etc) you could use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('2014'!$F:$F= B3)*('2014'!$H:$H= A13)*(Month('2014'!$A:$A) = 5)*1)
```

That will look for May values, for instance.

**How this works**:

`SUMPRODUCT` works by testing conditions across a range of cells. For each row, in our case, we test if `F` holds B13's value, `H` holds A13's data, and the Month of `A` is `5`. Each one of those tests will return a `TRUE` or a `FALSE`. A `TRUE` is also a `1` and a `False` is also a `0`, so testing a rows will look like:

```
Row 1:   TRUE  * TRUE * TRUE  * 1 = 1
Row 2:   FALSE * TRUE * TRUE  * 1 = 0
Row 3:   TRUE  * TRUE * FALSE * 1 = 0
Row 4:   TRUE  * TRUE * TRUE  * 1 = 1
--------------------------------------
TOTAL:                              2
```

Each condition is in it's own paranthetical statement and is multiplied by the other conditions so that it will result in a 1 or 0, which SUMPRODUCT will add up when it's done testing every row in your range.

Comment: Can you please explain how this works as it returns `#VALUE`, many thanks for your assisstance.

Comment: You bet. I just added a quick explanation of sumproduct. It's a fun one.

Comment: Ah fantastic, I will have a jiggle and see if I have missed anything that's causing my error, thank you!

Comment: If you use MONTH function on a text value then you get #VALUE! error, so if you have headers in row 1, for example, that will be a problem - try using specific row ranges rather than the whole column